# Partial specialization of member function

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, partial-specialization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“invalid use of incomplete type” error with partial template specialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165101/invalid-use-of-incomplete-type-error-with-partial-template-specialization)

Why is it that I can do this:

```
template <typename T>
struct A
{
    void foo(int);
};

template <>
void A<int>::foo(int)
{
}
```

but not this:

```
template <typename> struct C {};

template <typename T>
struct A
{
    void foo(int);
};

template <typename T>
void A<C<T> >::foo(int)
{
}
```

For the second case, GCC gives the following error:

```
test.cpp:10:23: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct A<C<T> >'
test.cpp:4:8: error: declaration of 'struct A<C<T> >'
```

**EDIT**:

When explaining why the second example is not allowed, please also consider that making the member function also a template has no effect on which example works and which does not. That is, this still works:

```
template <typename T>
struct A
{
    template <typename U>
    void foo(U);
};

template <>
template <typename U>
void A<int>::foo(U)
{
}
```

but this does not:

```
template <typename> struct C {};

template <typename T>
struct A
{
    template <typename U>
    void foo(U);
};

template <typename T>
template <typename U>
void A<C<T> >::foo(U)
{
}
```

So the reason cannot be that function templates can only be fully specialized, because the third example is not a full specialization (the template parameter `U` is still there), and yet it works.

Comment: @Mankarse that seems to be a different issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Function templates can only be specialised completely, not partially.

You're using the fact that member functions of class templates are themselves function templates, so this rule still applies.

---

As for your edit: The following things can be explicitly (i.e. completely) specialized, from 14.7.3/1:

> An explicit specialization of any of the following:
>
> — function template
>
> — class template
>
> — **member function of a class template**
>
> — static data member of a class template
>
> — member class of a class template
>
> — member enumeration of a class template
>
> — member class template of a class or class template
>
> — **member function template of a class or class template**
>
> can be declared by a declaration introduced by `template<>;`

I've emphasized the two statements that apply to your case. Absent any other explicit provisions, those entities can *not* be specialized partially.

Comment: I'm not sure I buy this explanation. Suppose I make the member function itself a template, with template parameter `U`. Then I can still define `A<int>::foo(U)`, but not `A<C<T>>::foo(U)`. However, the first can hardly be considered a full specialization, as it has a template parameter (`U`).

Comment: @HighCommander4: I said "member function", not "member template". If you change the question, I change the answer :-)

Comment: @HighCommander4: OK. Make sure you understand that `A<T>::foo` in its *entirety* is treated as a function template. There is no analogous concept for any other kind of class member, whether it be, value, type or template. *Only* member *functions* are special.

Comment: On second look, it still doesn't make sense. You said "Member templates enjoy no such special treatment, so they cannot be individually replaced", but in my third example, am I not individually replacing a member template function?

Comment: @HighCommander4: You're absolutely right. I looked it up now, see the edit.