# C++ template, static function specialization

Tags: c++, templates, static, inline, specialization

I have a syntax error with my template

I would like to partial specialize a static function of my template class

### class.hpp

```cpp
template <typename Foo, size_t bar = 26>
class MyClass
{
    MyClass();
    static void function();
};

#include "class.tpp"
```

### class.tpp

```cpp
template <typename Foo, bar>
MyClass<Foo, bar>::MyClass()
{ }

template <typename Foo>
inline
void
MyClass<Foo, 6>::function()
{
    // ...
}

template <typename Foo>
inline
void
MyClass<Foo, 26>::function()
{
    // ...
}
```

`error: template definition of non-template`

I just want to implement `MyClass<Foo, bar>::function` for bar == 26 and bar == 6

How to do that properly ?
Thanks

Comment: `template <typename Foo, bar>` is surely wrong

Comment: Use [tag-dispatching](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dfee575c1fb47b37) if you want to avoid specializing the entire class template

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function is not a template itself, it is only inside a class template. You can specialize the class for those cases, but not the function itself.

```
template <class Foo>
class MyClass<Foo, 26>
{
    static void function() { ... }
};
```

Provided you have specialized the class like so, you can only declare the function inside the class, and define it outside like so:

```
template <class Foo>
void MyClass<Foo, 26>::function() { ... }
```

If you don't specialize it beforehand, you'll get a compilation error for using an incomplete type.

You might also find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12875187/partial-template-specialization-outside-class-definition) question and answer on specializing a single function inside a class template relevant.

Comment: Yes, if I want to implement `function` outside the class, in class.tpp, how to do that properly ?
Because I know `function` is not a template function, but i don't know the good syntax for the prototype outside the template definition

Answer (score 2):

You cannot partial specialize method like that.

You may partial specialize the whole class.

or as alternative, you may forward the implementation to some helper:

- struct that you may specialize as you want.
- overload (using some dispatching):

  ```
  namespace detail
  {
      template <typename Foo, std::size_t bar>
      void function_impl(MyClass<Foo, bar>& that)
      {
          // Generic case.
      }

      template <typename Foo>
      void function_impl(MyClass<Foo, 6>& that)
      {
          // special case <Foo, 6>.
      }

      template <typename Foo>
      void function_impl(MyClass<Foo, 26>& that)
      {
          // special case <Foo, 26>.
      }
  }
      template <typename Foo, std::size_t bar>
      inline
      void
      MyClass<Foo, bar>::function()
      {
          detail::function_impl(*this);
      }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

After doing some research; Partial Specialization for member functions of a class template are not allowed, so one would have to specialize the whole class which can be a problem if the actual class is quite large. If you are trying to separate the implementation from the declaration having a wrapper or helper will work, but you must defined that and the partial specialization first. Check out this code here for it compiles, builds and outputs the appropriate values using MSVC 2015 CE.

**MyClass.h**

```
#ifndef MY_CLASS_H
#define MY_CLASS_H

#include <iostream>

// Helper - Wrapper Class
template<typename Foo, size_t Bar>
class specialized {
public:
    inline static void function();
};

// Partial Specialization
template<typename Foo>
class specialization<Foo, 6> {
public:
    inline static void function();
};

// Actual Class
template<typename Foo, size_t Bar = 26>
class MyClass {
private:
    specialized<Foo, Bar> func;
public:
    MyClass();

    inline void function(); // Works
    // inline static void function(); // Compiler Error
}; // MyClass

#include "MyClass.inl"

#endif // MY_CLASS_H
```

**MyClass.inl**

```
// Helper - Wrapper
template<typename Foo, size_t Bar>
inline void specialized<Foo, Bar>::function() {
    std::cout << "26" << std::endl;
} // function

// Specialized
template<typename Foo>
inline void specialized<Foo, 6>::function() {
    std::cout << "6" << std::endl;
} // function

// Constructor
template<typename Foo, size_t Bar>
MyClass<Foo, Bar>::MyClass() {
} // MyClass

// Class Member Function
template<typename Foo, size_t Bar>
inline void MyClass<Foo, Bar>::function() {
    func.function();
} // function
```

**MyClass.cpp**

```
#include "MyClass.h"
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include "MyClass.h"

int main() {
    MyClass<float, 6> a;
    a.function(); // Prints Out 6

    MyClass<float, 26> b;
    b.function(); // Prints Out 26

    MyClass<float> c;
    c.function(); // Prints Out 26

    MyClass<float, x != 6> d;
    d.function(); // Prints Out 26

    return 0;
} // Main
```