# template partial spcialization

Tags: c++, templates

```
template <typename T, unsigned D>
class Matrix
{
 public:
  T Determinant( void ) const;

  T m[D][D];
};


template <typename T>
T Matrix<T, 2>::Determinant( void ) const
{
  return m[0][0] * m[1][1] - m[1][0] * m[0][1];
}
```

Hello, forum.
I have this code, yet I get error:

```
1>c:\dropbox\projects\math\matrix.h(319): error C3860: template argument list following class template name must list parameters in the order used in template parameter list
1>c:\dropbox\projects\math\matrix.h(319): error C2976: 'Math::Matrix<T,D>' : too few template arguments
```

No Idea what is wrong. Please help.

Comment: I believe you can only specialize the entire class, not individual functions.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["invalid use of incomplete type" error with partial template specialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165101/invalid-use-of-incomplete-type-error-with-partial-template-specialization)

Comment: What you can do is make `Determinant` a non-member (possibly a friend) and *overload* it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide the definition for that class specialization. For instance:

```
template <typename T, unsigned D>
class Matrix
{
 public:
  T Determinant( void ) const;

  T m[D][D];
};

template <typename T>
class Matrix <T, 2>
{
  T m[2][2];    

public:
  T Determinant (void) const;
};

template <typename T>
T Matrix<T, 2>::Determinant (void) const
{
  return m[0][0] * m[1][1] - m[1][0] * m[0][1];
}
```

Without that, the compiler won't be able to tell if the specialized version of `Matrix<T, 2>` contains a `Determinant` method.

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible duplicate of [c++ template partial specialization member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15374841/c-template-partial-specialization-member-function)

As mentioned there, you do not specialize methods, but the class itself.