# Partial specialisation of member function with non-type parameter of a class with non-type parameter

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, specialization

I have a matrix class with a `toString()` method:

```
template <typename T, int rowCount, int columnCount>
class Matrix
{
//...
public:
    std::string toString() const
    {
        // ...
    }
};
```

Now I want to specialize `toString()` for the case, that `T` is `Matrix` so that it returns a string in a different format in the case of

```
Matrix<Matrix<double, 2, 2>, 3, 3> a;
std::string s = a.toString();
```

to say this case:

```
Matrix<double, 2, 2> a;
std::string s = a.toString();
```

I tried something like this

```
template <int rows, int cols>
template <typename X, int rows_inside, int cols_inside>
std::string Matrix<Matrix<X, rows_inside, cols_inside>, rows, cols>::toString() const
{
    //...
}
```

but it does not work.

How can I achieve this effect?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["invalid use of incomplete type" error with partial template specialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165101/invalid-use-of-incomplete-type-error-with-partial-template-specialization)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `if constexpr` to achieve this.

```cpp
template <typename, int, int>
class Matrix;

template <typename>
struct IsMatrix : std::false_type
{
};

template <typename T, int N, int M>
struct IsMatrix<Matrix<T, N, M>> : std::true_type
{
};

template <typename T, int rowCount, int columnCount>
class Matrix
{
    //...
public:
    std::string toString() const
    {
        if constexpr (IsMatrix<T>::value)
        {
            return "matrix";
        }
        else
        {
            return "not matrix";
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works perfectly.
Do you know if there is any way to achieve this with only C++11 features.

Comment: @Julian Aßmann I see at least three solutions, first one to use partial specialization and have two versions of your class, second you can use 'Tag Dispatching' (pass bool to underlying function with implementation), and third nearest to 'if constexpr' is to use std::enable_if. I wrote example for third approach: https://godbolt.org/z/Mbsnxz